# How to take first element from iterator/generator and put it back in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I would like to take first element from iterator, analyse it, then put it back and work with iterator as if it was not touched.

For now I wrote:

```
def prepend_iterator(element, it):
    yield element
    for element in it:
        yield element


def peek_first(it):
    first_element = next(it)
    it = prepend_iterator(first_element, it)
    return first_element, it

first_element, it = peek_first(it)

analyse(first_element)

continue_work(it)
```

it is possible to write better/shorter?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `peek_first` is called on an empty iterator? Do you just want to have it raise `StopIteration`, or do you want to "reset" so that it returns, say, `(None, it)` where `it` is an empty-but-not-yet-stopped iterator?

Comment: What is wrong with what you wrote? This is the only real approach that can work generally

Comment: check [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

Comment: See also [more_itertools.spy](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.spy) and [more_itertools.peekable](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.peekable).

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example wit [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)

```
import itertools
def colors():
    for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue']:
        yield color

rgb = colors()
foo, bar = itertools.tee(rgb, 2)

#analize first element
first =  next(foo)
print('first color is {}'.format(first))

# consume second tee
for color in bar:
    print(color)
```

output

```
first color is red
red
green
blue
```

EDIT (05 May 2022): To expand this answer, if you don't mind installing extra [third-party] package, there is [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/), that provide convenient tools to [lookahead and lookback](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#lookahead-and-lookback) when working with iterator. These tools peek at an iterable’s values without advancing it.

Comment: 2 is the default value for the n param, so could also be omitted: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee

Answer (score 3):

Here I present a simple method that exploits concatenation of generators.

```
import itertools
def concat_generators(*args: Iterable[Generator]) -> Generator:
    r"""
    Concat generators by yielding from first, second, ..., n-th
    """
    for gen in args:
        yield from gen

your_generator = (i for i in range(10))
first_element = next(your_generator)

# then you could do this
your_generator = concat_generators([first_element], your_generator)
# or this
your_generator = itertools.chain([first_element], your_generator)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Note this will only work if you're pushing back non-`None` values.***

If you implement your generator function (which is what you have) so that you care about the *return value of `yield`*, you can "push back" on the generator (with `.send()`):

```
# Generator
def gen():
    for val in range(10):
        while True:
            val = yield val
            if val is None: break

# Calling code
pushed = false
f = gen()
for x in f:
    print(x)
    if x == 5:
        print(f.send(5))
        pushed = True
```

Here, you're printing both the `x` from the `for` loop *and* the return value of `.send()` (if you call it).

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
5   # 5 appears twice because it was pushed back
6
7
8
9
```

This will only work let you push back once.  If you want to push back more times than that, you do something like:

```
# Generator
def gen():
    for val in range(10):
        while True:
            val = yield val
            if val is None: break

# Generator Wrapper
class Pushable:
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
        self._next = None

    def send(self, x):
        if self._next is not None:
            raise RuntimeError("Can't pushback twice without pulling")
        self._next = self.g.send(x)

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            while True:
                # Have to clear self._next before yielding
                if self._next is not None:
                    (tmp, self._next) = (self._next, None)
                    yield tmp
                else:
                    yield next(self.g)

        except StopIteration: return

# Calling code
num_pushed = 0
f = Pushable(gen())
for x in f:
    print(x)
    if (x == 5) and (num_pushed in [0,1,2]):
        f.send(x)
        num_pushed += 1
```

Produces:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5  # Pushed back (num_pushed = 0)
5  # Pushed back (num_pushed = 1)
5  # Pushed back (num_pushed = 2)
5  # Not pushed back
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: That only lets you peek an element once, and it fails if you try to peek a falsy element.

Comment: @user2357112 I can tighten it up to make it fail only for `None`, and peek as many times as you want, one moment

Comment: Also, you're ignoring the `send` return value. The way you've implemented things, the `send` call returns the pushed element, and the loop doesn't see it. [`5` doesn't actually get printed twice](https://ideone.com/dxf2Qt). (If you tested this in interactive mode, the `5` got autoprinted because Python's interactive autoprinting even happens in loops, even though that's more confusing than useful.)

Comment: I agree, deleting until I can clean it up properly.

Comment: @user2357112 yuck -- the push back multiple times "requirement" turned out pretty ugly